# Deleting/Merging questions without giving feedback

Tags: feature-request, new-users, deleted-posts

I'm new on SU but have been on SO for a while. Asked my first question (admittedly a broad one) which I assume got deleted by a mod. This in itself doesn't bother me in the slightest.

The fact that no feedback is given as to why a question is deleted could be very disconcerting for new users. And it'll probably take a while for them to get to the 10k posts mark to be able to view their deleted posts.

Could we get some sort of information when a question is deleted. Simply "Your message was deleted/merged because of X. Read the FAQ" would be far better than nothing at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your post was actually merged with a previous question because it was a duplicate and there were already 7 or so answers on yours, so I just merged it into the original.

I agree that when things get deleted/merged/etc. that there needs to be some sort of alert, otherwise people tend to get left wondering whether the system just ate their post or not.

Comment: BURN HIM! BURN HIM!

Comment: They call me the Mule-Kick Mauler!

Comment: Still think redirecting the old page to the new one would suffice... for all duplicates really, but especially for merged dups.

Comment: @Shog9: I agree. It's pretty strange how when a post gets merged there is absolutely no trace of it whatsoever.

Comment: If I delete or merge, I usually post a comment saying that I'm going to do it in an hour or two - this gives the OP some time to revisit the topic and see the note so they know what's going to happen. Barring more notification when questions get deleted/merged, I think it might be a good idea to set a timer so that an action can be performed automatically at a specified time in the future.

Comment: We need SO to redirect stuff. Right now there are almost no redirection in place, which in combination with the front page cache, leads to a lot of 404s

Comment: @TheTXI thanks for letting me know. I guess it just emphasizes my point to get feedback as i thought it had been deleted outright. I didn't see the “Must Have” Windows Software question during my initial search

Comment: I wonder if I can merge TheTXI account with someone else. *wonders out deep in thought*